# print python pattern for given value of N

Tags: python, string-matching

Example input: `7`

Output:

```
ABCDEFGGFEDCBA
ABCDEF  FEDCBA
ABCDE    EDCBA
ABCD      DCBA
ABC        CBA
AB          BA
A            A
```

Code:

```py
a = int(input())
for i in range(a):
    p = 65
    for j in range(i, a):
        print(chr(p), end="")
        p+=1
    print()
```

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: This is hard to read. Could you re-format this so that it's easy to read and understand. It might help you too

Comment: is it now ok sir?

Comment: some hints: a loop in reverse order can be created with `range(a, i, -1)`. To fill the gap between the two sides, you could print spaces.

Comment: This looks like a perfect situation to learn to use unit tests, which will let you automatically run your code with several different inputs all at once, without needing to go through the dance of manually running your program and trying a different number every time. I wrote some up for you, take a look: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/41a5b8b8e0aa5980273d1a84b77b1c66

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following codes

```
a = int(input())
for i in range(a):
    p = 65
    for j in range(i, a):
        print(chr(p),end="")
        p += 1

    for z in range(0, i*2):
        print(" ", end="")

    for k in range(a, i, -1):
        p -= 1
        print(chr(p), end="")

    print()
```

Comment: Please don't just give a code-only answer with no explanation. It has 0 educational value, and just spoils the exercise.